# printing a slash character in lua

Tags: lua, slash, watchmaker

I'm designing a watch using watchmaker which uses lua, and all i want to do is print the date "tue 2/13". I started with 
character
`{ddw} {dn}/{ddz}`

which returns " '' expected near '2' "

I tried wrapping all the requested bits in quotes, but it still fails, I've tried breaking them up in ()'s but I'm far from a lua expert and the syntax is far from my basic web practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints what you want:

```
print("tue2".."/".."13")
```